# itertools / takewhile -> gave me unexpected result [0]

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

```
from itertools import takewhile
list(takewhile(lambda x: x%2==0, range(10)))
```

Result that I want to see - even numbers:

```
[0,2,4,6,8]
```

Result that I get:

```
[0]
```

How is it possible, why it gave me zero?

Comment: because it took while the range wasn't an odd number? 1 is odd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is correct. Your understanding of [takewhile](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) seems to be flawed. Takewhile will only keep taking values from an iterable till you first fail a condition. When that happens, it will stop. Since `1` breaks the `lambda x: x%2==0` condition, thus the execution stops and `[0]` is returned.

If you wish to just filter values, you can use a list comprehension or filter as needed.

```
list(filter(lambda x: x%2==0, range(10))) #OR
[i for i in range(10) if i%2==0]
#output:
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 2):

`takewhile` will stop at the first odd number, use `filter` instead:

```
list(filter(lambda x: x%2==0, range(10)))
```

But for such a simple problem you don't even need `filter`, something like this will work aswell:

```
list(range(0, 10, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `filter` instead, like so:

```
list(filter(lambda x: x%2==0, range(10)))
```

`takewhile` returns elements while the specified condition is true. When it stops being true, the `yield`ing stops. This is not what you seem to be after.